# C++ Socket server application control

Tags: c++, sockets

I am working on a application which works by received commands (API calls) over a socket connection. The application has two socket server with two different port numbers. As said the application is acting on the received commands (string). What is the best way to setup the socket server(s)? The socket server object is been build in a class file and contains two threads (listen for connections, handling the new connected client). The question is, what will be the best way to use the received commands/data so that the application will respond to it. Should I buildin a buffer (vector of string) to store the received data, read this buffer in the main loop of the application and after the reading clear the vector? Or is there a better/ other way?

The code of the socket server class is:

```
void SocketServer::Startup()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsa);
    this->WorkerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    this->EndPnt.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    this->EndPnt.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->EndPnt.sin_port = htons(this->m_port);
    this->Enabled = true;
    this->ID = 0;
    bind(this->WorkerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&this->EndPnt, sizeof(this->EndPnt));
    printf("[SocketServer]Bound on %d..\n", this->m_port);
    listen(this->WorkerSocket, this->Backlog);
    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ServerMainThread, this, NULL, NULL);
}

void SocketServer::WaitForConnections(SocketServer * Ser)
{
    while(Ser->Enabled)
    {
        SOCKET accptsock = accept(Ser->WorkerSocket, NULL, NULL);
        printf("[SocketServer]Client connected.\n");

        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ServerDataThread, (LPVOID)accptsock, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

void SocketServer::WaitForData(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    SOCKET sock = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";
    send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);

    int res;
    char buffer[255];

    while(true)
    {
        res = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        if( res == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            int error_code = WSAGetLastError();
            if(error_code == WSAECONNRESET)
            {   
                //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                cout << "[SocketServer]Client disconnected" << endl;

                //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                closesocket(sock);
                ExitThread(0);
            }
            else
            {
                closesocket(sock);
                ExitThread(0);
            }
        }

        if(res == 0)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            ExitThread(0);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << buffer << endl;

            // insert data to vector here
            send(sock , buffer , sizeof(buffer) , 0 );
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI SocketServer::ServerMainThread(LPVOID lParam)
{
    ((SocketServer*)lParam)->WaitForConnections((SocketServer*)lParam);
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI SocketServer::ServerDataThread(LPVOID lParam)
{
    ((SocketServer*)lParam)->WaitForData((LPVOID)lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

The vector it needs to push the data to is called "Buffer", "Buffer.push_back(buffer)";

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You have the WaitForData thread: why do you need anything else? That thread should do all the I/O with the client.

Comment: If the client is making some API calls before disconnecting you could try websocketpp from https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp. Very convenient with send() and on_message(). What kind of client is it?

Comment: The main thread is drawing items on a screen. With the two socket servers, the user can send API calls (tcp). The two socket servers are two classes (one is running as a 'normal' TCP server, the other also but is used for HTTP requests so it has some different responses). I want to forward the received API calls to the main thread to be parsed and executed to control the drawing activity (add item, delete, update position etc).